# Can you make a YouTube analytics API request using Net::HTTP in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

Assuming my `access_token` and my `TEST_CHANNEL_ID` are correct, shouldn't this request work?

I'm getting a 404 error, am I missing some parameter?

```
uri = URI.parse("https://www.googleapis.com")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/youtube/analytics/v1/reports")
request.body = URI.encode_www_form({"Authorization" => "Bearer #{access_token}", "ids" => "channel==#{TEST_CHANNEL_ID}", "start-date" => "2015-07-01", "end-date" => "2015-07-20", "metrics" => "views"})

response = http.request(request)
```

It's worth mentioning that I obtained my `access_token` with a `refresh_token` authorized for all youtube api scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing the access token as a URL parameter, the name of the parameter should be "access_token" and you don't need the "Bearer" part of the string; it would just be:

```
request.body = URI.encode_www_form({"access_token" => "#{access_token}", "ids" => "channel==#{TEST_CHANNEL_ID}", "start-date" => "2015-07-01", "end-date" => "2015-07-20", "metrics" => "views"})
```

You only use the `Authorization: Bearer {whatever}`form if you're setting the access token in the request header.

[Here's the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi) on this.